# Writing text on LaTeX \part page

Tags: latex

I was wondering if it is possible to write an introductory text on the page generated by \part{...} in LaTeX?

I have tried to insert text on it, but it will just generate a blank page before the text.

Regards,
Kenneth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define own macro `\mypart`.
For example

```
\def\mypart#1#2{%
  \par\break % Page break
  \vskip .3\vsize % Vertical shift
  \refstepcounter{part}% Next part
  {\centering\Large Part \thepart.\par}% 
  \vskip .1\vsize % Vertical shift 
  % Some text
  #2
  \vfill\break % Fill the end of page and page break
}

\part{Main}{Something about main...}
```

Comment: Thank you Alexey! I ended up with the following:

\def\mypart#1#2{%
  \par\newpage\clearpage % Page break
  \vspace*{5cm} % Vertical shift
  \refstepcounter{part}% Next part
  {\centering \textbf{\Huge Part \thepart}\par}% 
  \vspace{1cm}% Vertical shift 
  {\centering \textbf{\Huge #1}\par}%
  \vspace{2cm}% Vertical shift
  % Some text
  #2
  \vfill\pagebreak % Fill the end of page and page break
}

Comment: I tried this way, but then the name of the part does not appear in the index page.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the memoir class then a simpler (but less general) method is to just redefine the `\afterpartskip` command.

I wrote:

```
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil}
```

in my preamble.

This works because the pagebreak is generated from

```
\newcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vfil\newpage}
```

in memoir.cls.  (It is called from the `\partpageend` command).

This method simply removes the `\newpage` command, which might be all you want to do.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I just wanted to add a figure below the part title. Then after inserting the graphics I can put in a \vfil and \newpage. Not a big deal, and much simpler than the other solutions.

Comment: I found this, in combination with adding `\nopartblankpage` let me add content to the part page.

Answer (score 1):

This solution works without any macro and with a correct entry in the Table of Content

```
\part[Title for TOC]{Title on part-page 
                             \\ \\ 
                  \begin{center}
                     \begin{minipage}[l]{11cm}
                       **Additional text on part page**
                     \end{minipage}
                  \end{center}
                 }
```

Comment: I like this solution. The only thing that bothers me is the formatting of the additional text. I added `\textnormal{\normalsize **text here**}` to get the fontsize back to normal, but the spacing between the lines stays large.

Comment: @JazZeus have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @SimonH can you elaborate on the question what exactly you do? Why do you center the minipage? Isn't centering default for parts? Why do you have two line breaks? Would \vspace do the job as well? The case is that in my case this solution works but as soon as I touch something, the whole text moves around on the page. I use the scrbook class.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for the srcbook class can be found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273340/old-code-to-define-part-in-scrbook-does-not-work-with-tex-live-2014-and-i-need which looks like this (I am citing):

```
\documentclass[10pt, german, twoside, openright, headings=small, bibliography=totoc, footinclude=false, mpinclude=false, headinclude, captions=tableheading, numbers=noenddot, cleardoublepage=empty, index=totoc
%, draft
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin 1]{inputenc}

\setkomafont{partnumber}{\Huge}
\renewcommand\raggedpart{\raggedleft}

\begin{document}
\setpartpreamble{%
  \vspace*{20pt}%
  Im Teil A dieses Buches soll zunächst anhand konkreter Beispiele aus Natur und Technik gezeigt werden, ...
}
\part{Einführung in wichtige Aspekte und Phänomene der Strömungsmechanik}

\end{document}
```